# UV mapping in Cycles

Tags: mesh, uv

I am new in blender and I am trying to do this simple shape but i faces a problem that my UV map dosen't fit the cylinder down there you can see a space with no image?? anybody had the same problem or it is something wrong I did? 
Thanks in advance

Blender file and texture incloded:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that an edge loop breaking the area that shows no print, or is that inner faces scaled to the same place as the outside faces, blocking the view of the texture?

Comment: Hi, No it is not the inner face it is a normal cylinder with one face bigger than the other and all the shape is one piece! Strange!

Comment: You should upload the blend file: this will help to understand what is wrong here... here is the link to do that: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Please pack the textures in it.

Comment: Thanks for comment @lemon : I will upload it tomorrow it is in the work computer.

Comment: The problem is due to the subsurface modifier. In fact all is correct about the UVs... but the modifier is doing so that the bottom gray part gets higher

Comment: So to solve the problem, you'll need to add edge loops to the side parts (and to unwrap the corresponding UV map part again)